# How to generate map based on the where condition

Tags: apex, map

I believe this question is more to logic.I have this query :

```
List<Period> periods = [SELECT StartDate, EndDate,FullyQualifiedLabel,Type,
                        Number,PeriodLabel FROM Period Where type = 'Month' AND   
                           (( StartDate <= 2017-05-22 AND EndDate >= 2017-05-22)  
                            or  (StartDate <= 2017-05-23 AND EndDate >= 2017-05-23 ) 
                            or (StartDate <= 2017-04-23 AND EndDate >= 2017-04-23 ))];
```

The result will be return like this :

[image]

Let say I have set that store the date that I used in query condition {2017-05-22,2017-05-23,2017-04-23}. How I am going to create Map that use these as key.
At the end, I would like to have map like this:

```
2017-05-22 ==> periods[0]
2017-05-23 ==> periods[0]
2017-04-23 ==> periods[1]
```

Note that 2017-05-22 and 2017-05-23 will have the same content.The only way that I can think of is to do loop inside the loop.

```
for(Period p : periods){

  for(Date d : setDate){
    if(p.StartDate<= d && p.EndDate>=d){
       mapPeriod.put(d,p);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit why do you need map like that? Probably, there are some other ways to make it working

Comment: It will be easy for me to get the value . For example I need to check which Month of  Opportunity Close Date in Organization calendar. I have to send close date to retrieve the Period , then I have to match back with Opportunity Close Date.The Period will not return same date with Close Date but it will return Start Date and Next Start Date. Using that map , I can simple get the value using Close Date as key.

Comment: I think for loop is the only way to achieve this.